# Un-wrap lines in a text file

Tags: array, go

I have a function which takes a `string` representing a text file, joins lines which were wrapped, and returns a slice with the wrapped lines. I'm interested in making my code maintainable, idiomatic, and fast (in roughly that order).

```
var startLine = "^([A-Z][A-Za-z ]+[0-9]+)- "
var startLineRegex = regexp.MustCompile(startLine)

// Given a block of text, split it into lines delimited by startLineRegex.
// This is specialized for the format used in CHANGES.
func splitIntoLines(text string) []string {
    lines := strings.Split(html.EscapeString(text), "\n")
    out := []string{}
    cur := ""
    for _, line := range lines {
        if cur == "" {
            cur = line
        } else if startLineRegex.MatchString(line) {
            out = append(out, cur)
            cur = line
        } else {
            // Line continuations start with many spaces, remove them.
            cur += " " + strings.TrimSpace(line)
        }
    }
    if cur != "" {
        out = append(out, cur)
    }
    return out
}
```

---

On request I've added input, output, and a simple driver.

Sample input:

```
   75- bnfnewprec could return a corrupt bnf structure:
        K=bnfinit(x^3-15667*x^2-88630960*x-1836105977032,1);
        bnfisprincipal(K,[29,14,15;0,1,0;0,0,1],3) -> oo loop
   76- agm(1,2+O(5)) -> SEGV [#1645]
BA 77- [cygwin64] ellap(ellinit([0,0,1,-1,0]),10007) broken
   78- primes([-5,5]) -> [5] (spurious absolute values)
   79- matqr([;]) -> crash
   80- Fp_rem_mBarrett could return a non-normalized result
       p=436^56-35;Mod(271,p)^((p-1)/2) -> p+1
   81- plotcopy would corrupt "string" objects (ROt_ST)
BA 82- [GP] default arguments to GP functions could cause corruption [#1658]
VBr83- [darwin] remove obsolete linker options that cause crashes [#1623]
   84- divisors([2,1]) -> SEGV                                    [#1664]
   85- acos([Pol(1)]) -> GC bug [#1663]
   86- matsolve(a,b) and a^(-1) gave wrong results [or SEGV] when t_MAT a
       was not square and a,b "modular" (F2m,Flm,FpM,FqM,F2xqM,FlxqM)
       same for x^(-1) [#1666]
   87- primes([1,Pol(2)]) -> SEGV [#1668]
   88- znlog(0,Mod(1,4),1) -> 0 (instead of [])
   89- polzagier / sumalt(,1) / sumpos(,1) were slow and used too much memory
   90- sumpos was wasting time when pre-computing \sum 2^e a(k*2^e) [ only
       needed for k odd, but was also done for k = 0 mod 4 ] + improve accuracy
   91- intnum(x=[0,-1/2],[oo,-3/2],1/(sqrt(x)+x^(3/2))) -> junk t_COMPLEX
       (more generally: one endpoint has an algebraic singularity and the
       other is +-oo, non-oscillatory
```

Sample output (one string per line)

```
   75- bnfnewprec could return a corrupt bnf structure: K=bnfinit(x^3-15667*x^2-88630960*x-1836105977032,1); bnfisprincipal(K,[29,14,15;0,1,0;0,0,1],3) -> oo loop
   76- agm(1,2+O(5)) -> SEGV [#1645]
BA 77- [cygwin64] ellap(ellinit([0,0,1,-1,0]),10007) broken
   78- primes([-5,5]) -> [5] (spurious absolute values)
   79- matqr([;]) -> crash
   80- Fp_rem_mBarrett could return a non-normalized result p=436^56-35;Mod(271,p)^((p-1)/2) -> p+1
   81- plotcopy would corrupt "string" objects (ROt_ST)
BA 82- [GP] default arguments to GP functions could cause corruption [#1658]
VBr83- [darwin] remove obsolete linker options that cause crashes [#1623]
   84- divisors([2,1]) -> SEGV                                    [#1664]
   85- acos([Pol(1)]) -> GC bug [#1663]
   86- matsolve(a,b) and a^(-1) gave wrong results [or SEGV] when t_MAT a was not square and a,b "modular" (F2m,Flm,FpM,FqM,F2xqM,FlxqM) same for x^(-1) [#1666]
   87- primes([1,Pol(2)]) -> SEGV [#1668]
   88- znlog(0,Mod(1,4),1) -> 0 (instead of [])
   89- polzagier / sumalt(,1) / sumpos(,1) were slow and used too much memory
   90- sumpos was wasting time when pre-computing \sum 2^e a(k*2^e) [ only needed for k odd, but was also done for k = 0 mod 4 ] + improve accuracy
   91- intnum(x=[0,-1/2],[oo,-3/2],1/(sqrt(x)+x^(3/2))) -> junk t_COMPLEX (more generally: one endpoint has an algebraic singularity and the other is +-oo, non-oscillatory
```

Driver code

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "html"
)

func main() {
    text,err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    lines := splitIntoLines(string(text))
    for _, line := range lines {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing your input and output really helps to make your code more understandable. Thanks for adding that detail.

It also makes it apparent that your logic is a little reversed. What you're doing is splitting on lines, and then joining where needed. What you should instead do, is split on the "keys", and then replace newlines. Let me explain.....

```
// Note flags - Non-capturing, and ^ matches start of line, not just start of text
var startChange = "(?m:[A-Z][A-Za-z ]+[0-9]+-) "
var startChangeRegex = regexp.MustCompile(startChange)
// match all end-of-lines surrounded by some, or no spaces.
var trimRegex = regexp.MustCompile("(?m) *$ *")

// Given a block of text, split it into lines delimited by startLineRegex.
// This is specialized for the format used in CHANGES.
func splitIntoLines(text string) []string {
    out := []string{}
    for _, change := range startChangeRegex.split(text) {
        change = trimRegex.ReplaceAllString(change, " ")
        out = append(out, change)
    }
    return out
}
```

Doing the split-on-change (with the non-capturing change regex) allows you to do a simpler "removal" of the newlines in each change. The result is... simpler.

Comment: Thanks! I knew something felt wrong about my code. :) As an aside, does this mean that you think that `append(out, change)` is the 'right' way to build up a slice?

Comment: The `append(...)` is the correct documented way to do it, yes. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices

Comment: Good to know. I used it because I knew it would work, but I didn't know if it was good practice or not. (I'm still learning Go.)